# Regex to move second line to end of first line

Tags: regex, xpath

I have several lines with certain values and i want to merge every second line or every line beginning with `<name>` to the end of the line ending with

```
 <id>rd://data1/8b</id>
 <name>DM_test1</name>
<id>rd://data2/76f</id>
 <name>DM_test_P</name>
```

so end up with something like

```
<id>rd://data1/8b</id><name>DM_test1</name>
```

The reason why it came out like this is because i used two piped xpath queries

Comment: does the linebreak really matter? shouldn't the xml parser just skip the whitespace? why do you need to have these elements in a single line?

Comment: What tools are at your disposal? [tag:sed], [tag:awk]?

Comment: okay I need to have them on the same line because they are both related to the same item. I couldnt find a way to using an xpath to retrieve all on the same line that why i piped.  sed, awk, glob, perl would work

Answer (score 0):

## Regex

Simply remove the newline at the end of a line ending in `</id>`. On a [windows](/questions/tagged/windows), replace `(<\/id>)\r\n` with `\1` or `$1` (which is [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) syntax). On a [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) search for `(<\/id>)\n` and replace it with the same thing.

## awk

The ideal solution uses [awk](/questions/tagged/awk). The idea is simply, when the line number is odd, we print the line without a newline, if not we print it with a newline.

```
awk '{ if(NR % 2) { printf $0 } else { print $0 } }' file
```

## sed

Using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) we place a line in the hold space when it contains `<id>´ and append the line to it when it's a`` line. Then we remove the newline and print the hold buffer by exchanging it with the pattern space.

```
sed -n '/<id>.*<\/id>/{h}; /<name>.*<\/name>/{H;x;s/\n//;p}' file
```

## pr

Using `pr` we can achieve a similar goal:

```
pr -s --columns 2 file
```

Comment: this wont work because the my output is being stored outputted in a different application (operations orchestration) so if i use a replace it doesnt recognise it as a regex....

Comment: Please provide more details, it's difficult to understand what you mean.

Comment: it is not working because I am using a regEx integrated within an automation application called HP operations orchestrations. Thus the application being temperamental and not processing. I even have a sed command that i can see would work but isnt "sed -e '$!N;/\n<name>/s/\n//'" the only regex that work within this application are formatted like "[^/]*$ "  so i need something similarly constructed

Comment: If you cannot replace, you cannot achieve this goal. Is there any way you can filter out chars using multiline regex?

Comment: How do you mean multi-lines? like run the same regEx multiple times til the end? I have another option of using a scriptlet?

Comment: What can the regex do, can you capture groups? Can you remove elements from a line? Does `<id>.*</id>\n<name>.*</name>` match two lines in the application or do regexes only work on a single line?

Comment: okay I think i understand what you mean, the regEx there stripped off information before a / in the list so <id>rd://data1/8b</id> it removed everything and left 8b. the regex you pasted below <id>.* that retrieves all the stuff in <id> the second part doesnt retrieve anything...